# Execution order of kotlin `.also {}` function

Tags: kotlin, logging

I know `.also { }` is intended to be used for logging. That is exactly what I want to do.

```
var count = 1
count++.also { print("count is $it") }
```

In this example I expect the log to be

> count is 2

But it actually prints:

> count is 1

Is there a way different way to use also here?

Comment: A `val` cannot be reassigned, that's why this shouldn't even compile (at least in my IDE, it doesn't), but if it does, it might ignore the `++` and prints just `1`. Make it `var count`... But it will still print `1` then.

Comment: Oh that was a tipo, sry.
It works with `count++.also { print(count) }` but not with `it`

Comment: @Punika it still wouldn't have compiled. see my edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not related to `also`.

You are using the postfix (`count++`) increment operator which returns the value of a variable before it has been incremented, which is `1`.

If you use the prefix increment (`++count`) operator it will first assign the new value and then return it, in this case `2`. Note that you need paratheses in this case:

```
(++count).also { print("count is $it") }
```

---

You mentioned that `also` is intended for logging. I don't think that is true. It is merelely a scope function which offers the receiver as `it` (or as you name it) inside the labmda and returns the receiver.

Comment: `++count.also { print(count) }` does not compile `Variable expected`

Comment: you need to use parentheses. `(++count).also { print("count is $it") }`

Comment: I added that to my answer.